# Traversing back to parent -> parent on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a page where when loaded there are multiple divs with class `classA`. But, on certain conditions of the contents of the div I want to change that class on page load

So in this example, based on content I want to change `classA` to `classB` - I'm using php for the variable check

e.g. code

```
<div class="classA">
    <div class="linkHolder">
        <? if($fruit=="apple"){ ?>
            <script>
                $(this).closest('.classA').toggleClass('classA classB');
            </script>
        <? } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This simply does not work. Should it? Is there a better way?

Comment: *"Should it?"* No. What do you expect `this` to refer to?

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see that - I was reusing code from a click, of course there is no $(this)

Answer (score 1):

you know you can do this without jquery?

```
<div class="<?php echo ($fruit=="apple") ? 'classB' : 'classA'; ?>">
    <div class="linkHolder">

    </div>
</div>
```